# Aligning table in one page pushing into right margins

Tags: tables, positioning, margins

Due to rules set by my research paper guidelines, I need to align certain text and tables related to it on one page. My problem is that fitting the table with its vales and content push it to the right margins. I have tried centering it and even aligning left, but it does not move from its position. How can this be resolved?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[square, comma, sort&compress]{natbib} 
\usepackage[none]{hyphenat}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage[rightcaption]{sidecap}
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}


\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]

\setlength\tabcolsep{1pt}
\begin{tabular}{ |P{1cm}|p{6cm}|P{2.1cm}|P{2cm}|p{5cm}|  }
\hline
\textbf{ID}& \textbf{Risk} &\textbf{Probability}& \textbf{Impact}& 
\textbf{Mitigation/Limitation} \\
\hline \hline
R1 & \textbf{Issues with Model}: aaaaa, aaaaa aaaaaaa, aaaaaaa aaaaaa & xssssyz & xyzxyz 
& aaaaa and aaaaa aaa aaaa aaaaa\\ \hline
R2 & \textbf{System Faults}: aaaaa, aaaaa bbbbbbbb aaaaaaa, aaaaaaa xxxxxxxxx aaaaaa & 
xyz & xyzxyz & aaaaa and aaaaa aaa aaaa aaaaa\\ \hline
R3 & \textbf{Outcome Unobtainable}: aaaaa, aaaaa aaaaaaa, aaaaaaa aaaaaa & xyz & 
xyzxaaaaavyz & aaaaa and aaaaa aaa aaaa aaaaa\\ \hline
R4 & \textbf{Delayed Deadlines}: aaaaa, aaaaa yyyyyy zzzzzzzzzzz yyyyyaaaa aaaaaaa, 
aaaaaaa aaaaaa & xyz & xyzxyz & aaaaa and aaaaa aaa aaaa aaaaa\\ \hline
R5 & \textbf{Difficulty developing models}: aaaaa, aaaaa aaaaaaa, aaaaaaa aaaaaa & xyz & 
xyzxyz & aaaaa and aaaaa aaa aaaa aaaaa zzzzzz zzzzzzz yyyyyy aaaaa xxxxxxx.\\ \hline
\end{tabular}

\caption{Risk Analysis Table}
\label{table:5}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Picture for reference:
[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You set the column widths explicitly. If you do this, you need to make sure, that the resulting table is not wider than `\textwidth` (that is, the width of the body text on the page. You got 1cm + 6cm + 2.1cm + 2cm + 5cm which is already 16.1 cm and you need to add 2 × 1 pt padding (the width defined by `\tabcolsep`) for every column. Together, this results in about 468.08 pt, which is obviously more than `\textwidth`, which is 345 pt in your set up.

Comment: Is there a way to adjust this using a package? I do not want to manually adjust it every time I write text.

Comment: There is the `tabularx` package which does a lot of calcultions for you (see the answer).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To avoid making the table wider than the text area, I would suggest to use [package `tabularx`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/tabularx):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[square, comma, sort&compress]{natbib} 
\usepackage[none]{hyphenat}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage[rightcaption]{sidecap}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
%\usepackage{showframe}% visualize the text area, head and marginpar column

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[ht]% note: h does not really work to place it always here
\setlength\tabcolsep{1pt}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|c|X|c|c|X|}
\hline
\textbf{ID}& \textbf{Risk} &\textbf{Probability}& \textbf{Impact}& 
\textbf{Mitigation/\newline\hspace*{\fill}Limitation} \\
\hline \hline
R1 & \textbf{Issues with Model}: aaaaa, aaaaa aaaaaaa, aaaaaaa aaaaaa & xssssyz & xyzxyz 
& aaaaa and aaaaa aaa aaaa aaaaa\\ \hline
R2 & \textbf{System Faults}: aaaaa, aaaaa bbbbbbbb aaaaaaa, aaaaaaa xxxxxxxxx aaaaaa & 
xyz & xyzxyz & aaaaa and aaaaa aaa aaaa aaaaa\\ \hline
R3 & \textbf{Outcome Unobtainable}: aaaaa, aaaaa aaaaaaa, aaaaaaa aaaaaa & xyz & 
xyzxaaaaavyz & aaaaa and aaaaa aaa aaaa aaaaa\\ \hline
R4 & \textbf{Delayed Deadlines}: aaaaa, aaaaa yyyyyy zzzzzzzzzzz yyyyyaaaa aaaaaaa, 
aaaaaaa aaaaaa & xyz & xyzxyz & aaaaa and aaaaa aaa aaaa aaaaa\\ \hline
R5 & \textbf{Difficulty developing models}: aaaaa, aaaaa aaaaaaa, aaaaaaa aaaaaa & xyz & 
xyzxyz & aaaaa and aaaaa aaa aaaa aaaaa zzzzzz zzzzzzz yyyyyy aaaaa xxxxxxx.\\ \hline
\end{tabularx}
\caption{Risk Analysis Table}
\label{table:5}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image: table using tabularx]

The `X`-columns all together will raise the table to the given width (`\textwidth` in the example). See the manual for more information.

But if you like, you could also center the table relative to the page using also the page margins:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[square, comma, sort&compress]{natbib} 
\usepackage[none]{hyphenat}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage[rightcaption]{sidecap}
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\usepackage{showframe}% visualize the text area, head and marginpar column

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]

\setlength\tabcolsep{1pt}
\centerline{\begin{tabular}{ |P{1cm}|p{6cm}|P{2.1cm}|P{2cm}|p{5cm}|  }
\hline
\textbf{ID}& \textbf{Risk} &\textbf{Probability}& \textbf{Impact}& 
\textbf{Mitigation/Limitation} \\
\hline \hline
R1 & \textbf{Issues with Model}: aaaaa, aaaaa aaaaaaa, aaaaaaa aaaaaa & xssssyz & xyzxyz 
& aaaaa and aaaaa aaa aaaa aaaaa\\ \hline
R2 & \textbf{System Faults}: aaaaa, aaaaa bbbbbbbb aaaaaaa, aaaaaaa xxxxxxxxx aaaaaa & 
xyz & xyzxyz & aaaaa and aaaaa aaa aaaa aaaaa\\ \hline
R3 & \textbf{Outcome Unobtainable}: aaaaa, aaaaa aaaaaaa, aaaaaaa aaaaaa & xyz & 
xyzxaaaaavyz & aaaaa and aaaaa aaa aaaa aaaaa\\ \hline
R4 & \textbf{Delayed Deadlines}: aaaaa, aaaaa yyyyyy zzzzzzzzzzz yyyyyaaaa aaaaaaa, 
aaaaaaa aaaaaa & xyz & xyzxyz & aaaaa and aaaaa aaa aaaa aaaaa\\ \hline
R5 & \textbf{Difficulty developing models}: aaaaa, aaaaa aaaaaaa, aaaaaaa aaaaaa & xyz & 
xyzxyz & aaaaa and aaaaa aaa aaaa aaaaa zzzzzz zzzzzzz yyyyyy aaaaa xxxxxxx.\\ \hline
\end{tabular}}
\caption{Risk Analysis Table}
\label{table:5}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image: table centered to page]

Note: The additional frames in the image are made by package `showframe` and only there to illustrate, that the table now uses both, the left and the right margin.

Another alternative would be to rotate the table using, e.g., [package `rotating`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/rotating):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[square, comma, sort&compress]{natbib} 
\usepackage[none]{hyphenat}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage[rightcaption]{sidecap}
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
%\usepackage{showframe}% visualize the text area, head and marginpar column
\usepackage{rotating}
\begin{document}

\begin{sidewaystable}[h]
\centering
\setlength\tabcolsep{1pt}
\begin{tabular}{ |P{1cm}|p{6cm}|P{2.1cm}|P{2cm}|p{5cm}|  }
\hline
\textbf{ID}& \textbf{Risk} &\textbf{Probability}& \textbf{Impact}& 
\textbf{Mitigation/Limitation} \\
\hline \hline
R1 & \textbf{Issues with Model}: aaaaa, aaaaa aaaaaaa, aaaaaaa aaaaaa & xssssyz & xyzxyz 
& aaaaa and aaaaa aaa aaaa aaaaa\\ \hline
R2 & \textbf{System Faults}: aaaaa, aaaaa bbbbbbbb aaaaaaa, aaaaaaa xxxxxxxxx aaaaaa & 
xyz & xyzxyz & aaaaa and aaaaa aaa aaaa aaaaa\\ \hline
R3 & \textbf{Outcome Unobtainable}: aaaaa, aaaaa aaaaaaa, aaaaaaa aaaaaa & xyz & 
xyzxaaaaavyz & aaaaa and aaaaa aaa aaaa aaaaa\\ \hline
R4 & \textbf{Delayed Deadlines}: aaaaa, aaaaa yyyyyy zzzzzzzzzzz yyyyyaaaa aaaaaaa, 
aaaaaaa aaaaaa & xyz & xyzxyz & aaaaa and aaaaa aaa aaaa aaaaa\\ \hline
R5 & \textbf{Difficulty developing models}: aaaaa, aaaaa aaaaaaa, aaaaaaa aaaaaa & xyz & 
xyzxyz & aaaaa and aaaaa aaa aaaa aaaaa zzzzzz zzzzzzz yyyyyy aaaaa xxxxxxx.\\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{Risk Analysis Table}
\label{table:5}
\end{sidewaystable}
\end{document}
```

[image: using sidewaystable]

There are several other possible solutions, like using a smaller font, using [package `pdflscape`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pdflscape), using [package `tabularray`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/tabularray) etc.

One additional note: Most tables look better, if you remove vertical lines and reduce horizontal lines. See the manual of [package `booktabs`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/booktabs) for information about good looking and good readable tables.

Comment: Thanks! I used \centerline to align my table with the text and it worked.